# How to convert Excel file to text file in php?

Tags: php, excel, file-conversion

I want to convert an excel file to a text file. I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
    $destination = 'products.xls';
    $section = file_get_contents($destination);
    $File = "file.txt"; 
    $File = str_replace(';','#',$File); 
    $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
    $Data = $section; 
    fwrite($Handle, $Data);
    print "Data Written"; die;
```

When I open the text file it shows me special characters and when I convert csv to text it shows me the right result. Please provide any helpful links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the Excel file that way. Excel file is binary file that follows the XLS format while file_get_contents is for pure text file. You need a library (like https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read the content then write to text.

Comment: but why its running fine on csv to text file?

Comment: because a csv file ___is___ a straight text file; xls or xlsx are __not__ text formats

Comment: there are too many php files in this libraray where i find my own any help?

Comment: You start by reading the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) and looking at the [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples)... what makes you think you need to read the code in every single file?